# How to select the current database in InfluxDB

Tags: mysql, influxdb, influxql

How can I get the current database name in Influx?

For example, we use `SELECT DATABASE();` in MySQL to get the db. Do we have any similar function in Influx?

Comment: Excuse my French, but RT*M: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/introduction/getting-started/

Comment: Re: Excuse my French, but RT*M: docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/introduction/getting-started
-------------
But I don't see any function there to show the current database, so your tone is not justified.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's no command to show the current database.